# How to asynchronously call a recursive function in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, recursion, socket.io

in my attempt to create an omegle clone using nodejs and socket.io for learning purposes, ive stumbled upon a problem that im not quite sure how to counter.

The socket id of clients and their interests are stored in an array of objects.
Then i use lodash to filter out other clients of similar interests. This is where i am stuck. If there are no clients with similar interests, the search should go on until one is found. So i decided to go with a recursive function with a callback, that upon finding a match fires the callback and if not, calls the function again.

That however led me to maximum call stack exceeded error.
Below is the function

```
    socketApi.funcy = function(socket_id, client_interests, callback){
    console.log("i am searching");
    search = _.filter(socketApi.availabe,{interests:client_interests});
    _.remove({socketID:socket_id});
    if(search.strlen>0){
        callback();
    } else {
        socketApi.funcy(socket_id, client_interests, callback);
    }
};
```

And below is the entire code of the whole thing

```
var socket_io = require('socket.io');
var _ = require('lodash');
var io = socket_io(3001);
var socketApi = {};
socketApi.rooms = [];
socketApi.available = [];
socketApi.taken = [];
socketApi.io = io;

socketApi.funcy = function(socket_id, client_interests, callback){
    console.log("i am searching");
    search = _.filter(socketApi.availabe,{interests:client_interests});
    _.remove({socketID:socket_id});
    if(search.strlen>0){
        callback();
    } else {
        socketApi.funcy(socket_id, client_interests, callback);
    }
};


io.on('connection',function(socket){
    console.log("User connected");
    socket.on('goChat', function(client_interests){
        socketApi.available.push({
            socketID : socket.id,
            interests : client_interests
        });        
        socket.emit('searching');

        socketApi.funcy(socket.id, client_interests, function(){
            console.log("okay i found a match");
        });
    });

    socket.on('msg',function(msg){
        console.log("received msg");
        room = rooms[socket.id];
        io.to(room).emit('msgrec',msg);
    });

});




module.exports = socketApi;
```

Can someone shed some light on the right way to do this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

if I understand your goal correctly, you are trying to search indefinitely until you find a matching client. If that's the case I would add a small timeout so it waits a second before trying again:

```
if(search.strlen>0){
    callback();
} else {
    setTimeout(socketApi.funcy(socket_id, client_interests, callback), 1000);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, tried that already and it doesn't seem efficient for this purpose either.

Comment: when do you mean not efficient? if you do it like in the question you it will search again and again at neck breaking speed until it runs out of call stack space.

Comment: Yes, even with the set time out its the same. I guess ill have to increase the interval or change the algorithm.